# How to install a web certificate on an Android device?

Tags: wi-fi, certificates

To gain access to WIFI at university I have to login with my user/pass credentials.

The certificate of their website (the local home page that asks for the credentials) is not recognized as a trusted certificate, so we install it separately on our computers.

The problem is that I don't take my laptop with me often to university, so I usually want to connect using my HTC Magic, but I have no clue on how to install the certificate separately on Android, it is always rejected.

This is what is stated in their website

### > Need for installation of official certificates CyberTrust validated by the CRU (http://www.cru.fr/wiki/scs/)

> ---
>
> The certificates contain information
>   certified to generate encryption keys
>   for data exchange, called "sensitive"
>   as the password of a user.
>
> By connecting to CanalIP-UPMC, for
>   example, the user must validate the
>   identity of the server accepting the
>   certificate appears on the screen in a
>   "popup window". In reality, the user
>   is unable to validate a certificate
>   knowing, because a simple visual check
>   of the license is impossible.
>
> Therefore, the certificates of the
>   certification authority
>   **(CRU-Cybertrust Educationnal-ca.ca Cybertrust and-global-root-ca.ca**)
>   must be installed prior to the browser
>   for the validity of the certificate
>   server can be controlled
>   automatically.
>
> Before you connect to the network-UPMC
>   CanalIP you must register in your
>   browser through the certification
>   authority
>   **Cybertrust-Educationnal-ca.ca** Download the
>   [Cybertrust-Educationnal-ca.ca](http://www.canalip.upmc.fr/doc/config/telechargement/Cybertrust-Educationnal-CA.cer),
>   depending on your browser and select
>   the link below :
>
> With Internet Explorer, click on the link following.
>
> With Firefox, click on the link following.
>
> With Safari, click the link following.
>
> If this procedure
>   is not respected, a real risk is
>   incurred by the user: that of being
>   robbed password LDAP directory UPMC. A
>   malicious server may in fact try very
>   easily attack type "**man-in-the-middle**"
>   by posing as the legitimate server at
>   UPMC.
>
> The theft of a password allows the
>   attacker to steal an identity for
>   transactions over the Internet can
>   engage the responsibility of the user
>   trapped ...

This is their website : http://www.canalip.upmc.fr/doc/Default.htm (in French, Google-translate it :))

Anyone knows how to install a web certificate on Android?

Comment: Is your Phone locked down or do you have access to the filesystem?

Comment: I think I can access to the file system, there is the debug mode that give you a root access, but what this have to do with certificates?

Comment: So just browsing to that site does not give you some option to permanently accept the certificate?

Comment: No, actually the browser asks to ignore the certificate, when I hit yes, it shows a failure page. This happens even on a pc, FireFox fails also to load a page even if I tell it to ignore the certificate, so if I download it separately and double click it, everything works normally

Comment: http://abtevrythng.blogspot.com/2010/06/adding-cer-certificates-on-your-android.html Shows how to actually achieve this. Worked fine for me. Try it out.

Comment: Rather than stating in your question that you solved the problem, you should create a new answer with the solution, then accept that answer.

Answer (score 5):

For Android 2.2, the certificates (*without renaming or converting*) can be placed at the root of the sd card.

To install:

1. Go to the **Settings/Security** menu, **Credential storage** section.
2. Activate **Use secure credentials**.
3. Click **Install from SD card**.
4. A menu will appear with the available certificates.
5. Click on each certificate to install.

Those certificates will then be available to the wifi system.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late coming, but I designed a tool just for this purpose.  I was having trouble with my Droid, so I created this tool: [RealmB's Android Certificate Installer](http://www.realmb.com/2010/01/android-certificate-installer/). I know it works with Android 2.0 (the OS which runs on the Droid), but I don't know for 1.5 or 1.6.  Feel free to give it a try.

Comment: actually I found a tool called wifihelper that do just that and it works for 1.5 and 1.6, check out this post here http://www.martani.net/2009/11/install-wpa-certificates-cer-files-on.html

Comment: the martani.net app was complex, so I cannot be sure I used it right; in any case, I followed instructions and it didn't seem to have any effect.

I also tried RealmB's installer, and that appeared to "work", in the sense that when I pointed my phone's browser at the link that the site provides, the phone popped up a dialog asking me what name to give the certificate.  On the other hand, I still cannot connect to my wireless network :-|

Answer (score -2):

I've done it typing in the browser "file:/" plus the name of the certificate file in the SD